# Summing several columns and keep the summed value only

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm practicing data manipulation with `iris`. I'm trying to sum the `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Width` to one column. I referred to this question [In R, how to replace values in multiple columns with a vector of values equal to the same width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986932/in-r-how-to-replace-values-in-multiple-columns-with-a-vector-of-values-equal-to)

got the sum but the `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Width` are not removed. Please help. Thanks a lot.

My code was

`iris <- iris %>% mutate(rowSums(iris[,c(2,4)]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native `dplyr` way to sum columns, and as specified in `?mutate`, `Use NULL to drop a variable.`:

```
iris %>% 
    mutate(Sepal.Length + Petal.Length, Sepal.Length = NULL, Petal.Length = NULL)
```